# Mutation or commit not working when page reload in nuxjs store

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

Vuex commit not working inside axios then block.
When I try to commit after axios get request it not working. The get request is working because .. If I try to log response it logging in my terminal.

```
export const state = () => ({
  user : {}
})

export const mutations = {
  set_user: (state, data) => state.user = data
}

export const actions = {
  initAuth(vuexContext, token){
    if( token ){

      /**
       * This commit working
       */
      vuexContext.commit('set_user', {name: 'sunny'})

      /**
       * But if I want to commit after this get request, it not working,
       * But consoling correct response
       */
      this.$axios.$get('/me')
      .then(res => {
        vuexContext.commit('set_user', res)
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err.response))
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: can you show the `console.log(res)`

Comment: Yes. I can see the response or result in console(Nuxt Server Side )

Comment: `{ 
  name: 'suman',
  id: '121'
}
`

Comment: I doubt it is as simple as that. Normally you would commit your mutation with `res.data` or `res.data.user` or some such.

Comment: I am tyred with like that `.then(res => { vuexContext.commit('set_user', {name: 'User Name', id: 100}) })`

Comment: What I mean is the response will be a nested object. So, from this: `.then(res => {` the "res" or "response" will be something like this: `data: { user:{ name: 'suman', id: 121 } }`. That's why I wanted you to show the full console.log

Comment: what do u mean by not working? what error? what do u expcet vs what happens?